# Terminal: 'Command Not Found'

Tags: installation, babeljs, eslint

Been getting answers here for years but this is my first time posting here ***hey guys***.

So basically I keep getting a 'Command Not Found' error on my terminal + VS Code terminal. At first I thought it was just 'eslint' as it kept throwing '*eslint:command not found*' even **after** installing it.

But as I've moved onto something else. I'm now seeing '*babel:command not found*'

My process for installing Babel + ESLint was:

npm install eslint --save-dev

npm install --save-dev @babel/core
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env
npm install --save-dev babel-cli

Basically I just want to be able to use the commands 'eslint' + 'babel' without an error being thrown up. Thanks!

I have a Mac OS and I use VSCode.

Comment: Can you state what command do you use that it output the error and what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a simple reset was all that was needed... thanks  Alexander tho!